# Web API post array of objects?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I have an object as follows which is then stored in an array of them.

I would like to send the array of them to Web API, usually you would use JSON.stringify on an object, but would this work also being in an array?

I then need to work out what type of object they would be received as the other end as I need to iterate through them. I was hoping to use a typeof class.

```
var fieldarray = [];
$("div[class*=container_]").each(function (index) {
    var firstElement = $(this).first();
    var object = $(this).find('.object');
    fielddata = {
        id: firstElement.attr('class').match(/\d+/)[0],
        attributes: [{
            'label_text': firstElement.text(),
            'label_width': firstElement.width(),
            'label_height': firstElement.height(),
            'label_color': firstElement.css('color'),
            'Field_Width': object.width(),
            'Field_Height': object.height,
            'Field_Type': object.attr('Field_Type'),
            'PositionX': firstElement.offset().left,
            'PositionY': firstElement.offset().top,
            'Field': firstElement.attr('class').match(/\d+/)[0],
            'Label_Font': firstElement.css('font-family')
        }]
    }
    array.push(fielddata);
});
```

Can I send this using JSON.stringify, and if so, what type would I receive this as in the Web API server side?

I usually use a public class type but the above code has an object inside an object - that is my problem.

Comment: So what is your actual question?

Comment: Can I send this using JSON.stringify, and if so, what type would I receive this as in the Web API server side?

Comment: I'd send the array as it is within the request body and would expect a `IEnumerable<dynamic>` on the server side, no?

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted this now, basically I used:

```
 [HttpPut]
        public int Put(int id, [FromBody] FormData HTMLFORM)
        {
....
}
```

and stored it in my type class as a string:

```
   public class FormData
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string HTML { get; set; }
            public string fieldData { get; set; }
        }
```

I then used

```
IList<AttributeData> findingList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<AttributeData>>(HTMLFORM.fieldData);
```

And it was stored in the list which I can iterate through using my type class of AttributeData!

Thanks